# Google Maps SDK - Core Data

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-data

I use the Google Maps SDK for iOS in my application who use Core Data.
When I want show the view who contain the map , my application crash with this exception :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is
>   not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'

There is maybe a conflict between my application who use Core Data and the sdk who also use Core Data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add an observer on the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification ? If so, do you check that the context passed with the notification is the same you use in your app (not the google maps one !) ?

Comment: @Guerrix check the implementation of the notification here : https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/